# Packages Install But Don't Display?

Tags: 12.10

I'm having yet another problem with Ubuntu 12.04 today. Whenever i download a package from the Ubuntu Software Center, it installs but doesn't show anywhere on the computer at all. For example, i installed UFRaw and looked in the launcher for the icon to start it up. But it's not there.

I've done a whole system search but no programs i've installed will display.

Can someone offer me some guidance of what to do please? Thanks.

Comment: have you tried running it from the terminal?

Comment: Yes i've already tried running from the terminal with no luck.

Comment: @UbuntuRob Please explain "no luck". What package does it concern? What command do you run? What would you expect it to do? and what is the actual output of the command in the terminal?

Comment: Problem solved! Asked the same question on the Ubuntu forums and got the answer in a matter of hours. Solution was to simply run via the terminal. Thanks!

Comment: And that was exactly the solution we were talking about. If only you cared to explain! :)